# Searching for specific date in log file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0, powershell-core

I have been tinkering with parsing through log files and attempting to see if specific errors are reoccuring.

Backstory: So what I have done is search for keywords of said error, (assuming it does not return null) grab the date-timestamp based on the last error generated, and re-search the log using the date as the pattern identifier in the select-string cmdlet. The point is to see if the error reoccurs after the last error date stored, since the log is being actively written to.
So for example, in my log file, I have a line that goes like this:

> [2020-02-22 22:22:22,222] @ and error has occured at error

okay neat. I already grabbed the date from earlier and stored it in my $date variable, specifically:

`$date = "2020-02-22 22:22:22,222"`

so now my next line of code is

```
Get-content -path c:\test\test.txt -Tail 1800 | Select-String -pattern $date -Context 0,1000
```

...but it doesn't return anything. Not even an error. its as if it is showing the output being null, even though i know my log has said date stamp since i parsed it two code lines before and stored the date as a variable. I have used single quotes, double quotes and no quotes, which all result in nothing being returned.

**How do I go about searching a log file for an exact date match that is stored in a variable?**

Comment: You can try adding the `-SimpleMatch` parameter to `Select-String` which makes it treat `-Pattern` as a literal string instead of a RegEx pattern. I don't see how your date string would cause RegEx issues, but maybe I'm missing something, or your date isn't quite how it appears in your example. Also, are you sure that your `-Tail` didn't force that date to scroll off the top?

Comment: Negative. For example, if i create a variable, say, $test = "error has occured at error" and use $test instead of $date, it returns the output beautifully.

Comment: I also do not see a good reason for this.  Double-check again that $date really contains what you think it does and that somewhere in the last 1800 lines of your test.txt file that string really does exist.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is maybe a file encoding discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

> How do you get an exact date match

Call `[Regex]::Escape()` and you'll always have an exact match on literals. See `$date2` below.

## Here's my sample log

```
$sample = @'
[info] Line1: stuff
[warn] Line2
[2020-02-22 22:22:22,222] @ and error has occured at error
[warn] line4
[verbose] line5: more
'@
```

## Passed as one line gives unexpected results

`Select-String` expects a list of strings. `$Sample` is currently 1 string with newlines in it. So if you were to use it like this, it returns the entire string -- even with context set to 0.

```
$date = '2020-02-22 22:22:22,222'

# or this automatically escapes special regex chars for you:
$date2 = [Regex]::Escape('[2020-02-22 22:22:22,222]')
$sample  | Select-String -Pattern $date -Context 0,0
```

[image]

## `-Context` works when passing a list of strings / lines

```
$sample -split '\r?\n' | Select-String -Pattern $date -Context 1, 1
```

Returns the wanted lines:

```
[warn] Line2
[2020-02-22 22:22:22,222] @ and error has occured at error
[warn] line4
```

## Converting log lines to a`DateTime` object

```
# the date format almost automatically detects it. Replacing fixes it.
$lineFromLog = '2020-02-22 22:22:22,222' -replace ',', '.'
$datetime_line = [datetime]$lineFromLog
```

[image]

## Filtering better than exact dates

First, the new log and `regex`

```
$sample2 = @'
[2020-02-21 22:00:22,222][info] Line1: stuff
[2020-02-22 22:04:31,113][warn] Line2
[2020-02-22 22:22:22,311] @ and error has occured at error
[2020-02-22 23:22:22,215][warn] line4
[2020-02-23 22:22:22,412][verbose] line5: more
'@

$regexLog = @'
(?x)
    \[(?<DateTime>[^\]]*)\]
    (?<Rest>.*)
'@
```

That regex is used to create a `PSCustomObject`

```
$parsed = $sample2 -split '\r?\n'
| ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match $regexLog) {
        # This could be improved by using '[datetime]::ParseExact'
        $datetime = try {
            [datetime]($matches['Datetime'] -replace ',', '.')
        } catch {
            $datetime = $matches['DateTime']
        }
        $hash = @{
            'Datetime' = $datetime
            'Rest'     = $matches['Rest']
        }
        [pscustomobject]$hash
    }
}
```

[image]

You can select your target date using a date object. This lets you use the `greater than or equal to` operator. You can extend it so you could filter by severity in combination with dates.

```
$targetDate = [datetime]'2/22/2020 10:22:22 PM'
$parsed | Where-Object DateTime -GE $targetDate

# and the second one limits the count
$parsed | Where-Object DateTime -GE $targetDate | Select-Object -First 2
```